# PHP 7.4, NGINX, Laravel 8 - only shows index page, all routes show 404

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have put a Laravel 8 application on a AWS t2.nano Linux AMI ec2 instance. I would like to start up front by saying I have been at this for about a day now. I have tried a few configurations.

Here's some configurations I have tried:

1. The default nginx config file from the Laravel 8 documentation
   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx
2. Another very similar stackoverflow question referenced here
   [Laravel on nginx says 404 for all routes except index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311586/laravel-on-nginx-says-404-for-all-routes-except-index)

At the end of the day, I cannot get it to work properly. My index page loads, but any of the other routes end up at a 404 page. You can view the application here.
https://technology.dvemedia.com/

So here are some tech specs and the current state of my conf file.

- Laravel - 8
- PHP - 7.4
- NGINX - 1.12.2

```
# HTTP
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name technology;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # Redirect to www
}

server {

     listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name technology.dvemedia.com;

    root /var/www/html/technology/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong, because I cannot get it to route to save my life.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
## Nginx php-fpm Upstream
upstream dvemedia {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

## Web Server Config
server
{
    ## Server Info
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name technology.dvemedia.com;
    root /var/www/html/technology/public;
    index index.html index.php;
    
    ## DocumentRoot setup
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    
    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }
 
    ## Rewrite all request to index
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
 
    ## Execute PHP scripts
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        expires          off;
        fastcgi_pass     dvemedia;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include          fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

and put all your optimisation/tweaks (like `fastcgi_buffers` ...) in `fastcgi_params` file

Comment: there is a slight typo on line 11, it should be "listen", but unfortunately this just gives me a 502 error now. Both my index page and every other route are all throwing a 502 error. @Latheesan

Answer (score 0):

I made a bad assumption by thinking my php-fpm socket would stay the same. After looking at the directory structure, my socket for 7.4 ended up being here.

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;`

That actually fixed it and everything worked. I gave bad information when I wrote the path for my socket was actually this.

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;`

@Latheesan answer would most likely have worked had I had given the correct information, minus the spelling mistake of course.